# How to get access token using refresh token in DocuSign and PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, refresh-token

I want to update my access token using the previous refresh token in DocuSign? I am getting

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Below is how I made the request.

```
$client_id = env('DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_ID');
        $client_secret = env('DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_SECRET');

        $encoded_client_id = utf8_decode(base64_encode($client_id));
        $encoded_client_secret = utf8_decode(base64_encode($client_secret));

        $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . "{$encoded_client_id}:{$encoded_client_secret}";
        // $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}"));

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $data = array(
            'refresh_token' => "My refresh token from previous successful request",
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . "{$encoded_client_id}:{$encoded_client_secret}";
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        $headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        Log::info($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who stuck on this issue:
The solution was just to change the content-type from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to application/json

Answer (score 1):

So, not confident that's the only issue, but the way you encode the `clientId` and `clientSecret` is different, you encode each part separately, instead of the whole thing with the colon.

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/authorization-code-grant-refresh-tokens shows that it's done like this:

```
string codeAuth = (clientId ?? "") + ":" + (clientSecret ?? "");
byte[] codeAuthBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeAuth);
string codeAuthBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(codeAuthBytes);
```

Note that the string that's encoded already had them combined, not each of them encoded separately.

Now, the error can also be because the Integration Key (IK or clientID) is not configured correctly, you use a bad refreshToken, it expired, you use the wrong environment (developer vs. production) and maybe a couple more reasons I forgot. Need to triple check all the values to ensure this if still not working.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Before doing the encoding separately, I did some thing like this: $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}")); which I use to get the first access token and refresh token using "authorization_code" as a grant_type, But to update the access token I used "refresh_token" as grant type, Second the refresh token is not expired since I got it a few minutes ago, and I am sure I am hitting developer environment url. May be i am using free version of docusing and I don't know if that is the case

Comment: Can you check the IK configuration?

Comment: How did you create this IK?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $post = array(
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $code,
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);     This is how I get the first access toeken and refresh token and I have used Authrization Code Grant as authentication on docusign admin dashboard

Comment: I don't get you when you say Check IK configuration, To be clear with you my client id is my Integration key and I have combined it with secret key to send it as authrization as follow        $integrator_and_secret_key = "Basic " . utf8_decode(base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}"));

Comment: Can you try to use https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/ ? and pick PHP? this will create a new IK and configure it correctly for you

Comment: I did as you suggest and I found a message in the readme file of the project,  which says: * Authentication with DocuSign via [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode).
When the token expires, the user is asked to re-authenticate. The refresh token is not used.

Comment: So can't we use the refresh token if we use Authorization Code Grant??

Comment: You can, but what I mean is that the code you had in this question above, you should run it with the IK (clientId), and clientSecret that were created for you by quickstart, the new set of configuration, not the old one

Comment: Can you try that?

Comment: Sure Let me try with new keys and let you know soon

Comment: Still the same error, unsupported grant type

Comment: So, the refresh token you are sending is the new one? that you obtained with the new keys?

Comment: yes the refresh token i am sending is created with new keys

Comment: Do you get a GUID that we can use to look at the logs? something called traceToken? I'm not sure what the issue is, may need to get help from support

Comment: You can send me an email with your IK (clientID) and we can try to look at the logs

Comment: inbar.gazit@docusign.com

Comment: Sure I will send you the key